# Am I allowed to advertise my question?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

Many times, it happens that you have got 6-7k views on your question, and need a few more to get a golden badge. Now, if it is unlikely that the question would get that more views on its own, am I allowed to explicitly advertise it?

Comment: What do you define as 'advertising' your question?

Comment: Simply, go to some website and pay them to display my question on their page..

Comment: Are you allowed to pay a 3rd party site for a link to an SE site? Sure, knock yourself out

Comment: It is your content, you authored it. You get to do whatever you want with the text. Stack Exchange encourages you to share links to your post. We cannot prohibit you from doing anything like that. It's your money!

Comment: So it comes down to what is allowed on the site you are advertising on. If you posted the link to another SE site, that'd be frowned upon, for example, not because you are posting a link but because you are in the wrong place doing so.

Comment: That's what the "share" link is for, isn't it? To "share" (i.e., "advertise") your post on other sites. If you want to spend money on internet merit badges, more power to you. Hey, can I have $5?

Comment: So, everyone agrees that he can, and I find this to be a good &interesting question - so, why the downvotes?

Comment: Allowed? Of course! But why should you do that? If you really want to spend your money and time just to get a "gold badge", then do it! No one will stop you, but just weigh your decisions before you do it so you won't regret it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well ask yourself an honest question, really - are you here to *play* or are you here to *learn/contribute*?

Nobody is stopping you from advertising it on any other social networks, feel absolutely free to do so. If you advertise it here just to get more views in order to obtain a badge and *NOT* to get an answer, you may get some negative feedback.

But bear in mind, that it's **your** time invested in an activity that this site hasn't been really designed for. The award system motivates people to **ask** better questions and **respond** with better answers. It wasn't primarily designed to be a social game per se.

Comment: "It wasn't primarily designed to be a social game per se", but that's how many play it. It's a system, and as soon as system springs into being, people stat trying to game it

Comment: @Mawg absolutely agreed. Still it wasn't *meant* to be a game, now, was it? The gamification aspect should incentivise people to answer questions with good and helpful answers. In the same way it incentivises people to ask questions that haven't been solved yet. What are the gains of gaming the system anyway? Will it give you better answers for your programming questions? Will it make you a better programmer? I don't know, it just seems a waste of time to hunt down rep points for the sake of the points.

Comment: I really don't know what the motivation might be - resume/CV, perhaps? Perhaps @anshabhi would tell us?

Answer (score 10):

> am I allowed to explicitly advertise it?

Allowed? Sure, it's your question. While the question also belongs to the community as whole (so you're not allowed to just delete or alter it without a good reason), nothing is stopping you from posting links to the question anywhere you want.

Is this good idea? If you ask me the answer is "no". Paying real money and/or spending real time on getting a virtual badge isn't a good practice in my opinion. Badges should come as a pleasant surprise, as Jeff once said. While hunting for badges is also good sometimes, spending too much time and efforts over this might reduce your overall "efficiency" towards SO/SE as whole.

Answer (score 9):

This depends entirely on the website you promote it on. We can't answer this for other sites, you'll have to check yourself what the rules are for each site.

In case you want to promote your own question on Stack Exchange, this is problematic in most cases. Bounties are the supported method to gather more attention to your question, almost all other methods are inappropriate. What you shouldn't do is e.g. commenting on unrelated questions or promoting the question in chat rooms you aren't active on.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you post spam  suggesting to take a look at your questions, or be annoying (say, in the chat) posting continuously posting messages regarding one question just to gain more views, that's absolutely allowed to advertise your questions on, maybe, sites of your own, and even encouraged.

There are some badges regarding sharing your questions - [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer), [Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster), [Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist) (which, by the way, won't work if you spread the links within SE). Also, every post has "share" under it that allows you to either copy the link or share it via social networks in convenient way. You can put those links on your site and have no problems.